# git heroku best way to update project

Tags: git, heroku

sorry for the beginner question, but I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.
I am a beginner with heroku, node.js and git!

I have deployed a node js app to heroku following this guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Everything works properly and I don't have problems.
My question now is how to update the files in heroku while I am working?

At the moment I do this:

git commit -m "some message"

and then

git push heroku master

it works, but it looks like it is re-creating the whole app from scratch.

Am I following the right procedure?
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are following the correct procedure for updating your Heroku app.
When you git push to Heroku, your code is received by the "slug compiler" which transforms your repository into a slug. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I will read something more..
So I need to git push both to heroku and to github to keep my project updated.. is there any way to sync those without doing two pushes?

Comment: You can use the Heroku Github Integration (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration). That way, you can configure auto-deploys to heroku whenever you push to a github branch of your choice.